# CSS Possible build many button with same width using padding

Tags: html, css, button

I tried build button with css using padding.

Html : (2 button)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style-login.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome-4.0.3.css" />

<div class="omb_login">
    <div class="omb_socialButtons">
        <button class="btnfb">
            <i class=" fa fa-facebook" data-size="icon" data-scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();"></i>
                Login With Facebook
        </button>
        <button class="btngoogle">
            <i class="fa fa-google" data-size="icon"></i>
                <a href="<?php echo $google; ?>">
                    Login With Google
                </a>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

//style-login.css
/*Style Facebook Login */
.omb_login  {
text-align: center;
line-height: 300%;
color: white;
display: block;
}

.btnfb {
-moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #88accb;
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #88accb;
box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #88accb;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#4189c4', endColorstr='#3975a8',GradientType=0);
background-color:#4189c4;
-moz-border-radius:3px;
-webkit-border-radius:3px;
border-radius:3px;
border:1px solid #2e6697;
display:inline-block;
cursor:pointer;
color:#ffffff;
font-family:Verdana;
font-size:14px;
font-weight:bold;
padding:0px 55px;
text-decoration:none;
text-shadow:0px 0.1px 0px #FFFFFF;
}

.fa-facebook {   // Symbol Facebook
margin-right:12px;
}

.btngoogle {
-moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #F8A088;
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #F8A088;
box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #f8a088;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#eb5d37', endColorstr='#dc5835',GradientType=0);
background-color:#eb5d37;
-moz-border-radius:3px;
-webkit-border-radius:3px;
border-radius:3px;
border:1px solid #bb4a2b;
display:inline-block;
cursor:pointer;
color:#ffffff;
font-family:Verdana;
font-size:14px;
font-weight:bold;
padding:0px 64px;
text-decoration:none;
text-shadow:0px 0.1px 0px #FFFFFF;
margin-top:10px;
}

.fa-google {   // Symbol Google
margin-right:12px;
}
```

Result:

[image]

It's not same (width fb & google), already change padding and still didn't same.

It's possible build button with same width using padding (not using width/height) or justify?

Sorry I not good in css, any Advice?

Comment: it depends on what is the content on the button.You cant have same width  because of text content of the button.

Comment: @NelsonTan yeach that my problem, because the text is not same size and different word.

Comment: I have that case for so many times and padding really wont work. you need to set the width to achieve a perfect size for all buttons.

Answer (score 0):

well because the length of the text is different , the two buttons won't look exactly the same without setting  the same width to both of them. it's logical. but you can align the icons if you want.

to do that , the icons must stay independent of the button text, so you need to use `position:absolute` on the icons and position them.

see snippet below

```css
.omb_login  {
text-align: center;
line-height: 300%;
color: white;
display: block;
}

.btnfb {
-moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #88accb;
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #88accb;
box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #88accb;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#4189c4', endColorstr='#3975a8',GradientType=0);
background-color:#4189c4;
-moz-border-radius:3px;
-webkit-border-radius:3px;
border-radius:3px;
border:1px solid #2e6697;
display:block;
cursor:pointer;
color:#ffffff;
font-family:Verdana;
font-size:14px;
font-weight:bold;
padding:10px 0;
width:300px;
text-decoration:none;
text-shadow:0px 0.1px 0px #FFFFFF;
position:relative;
}

.fa-facebook { 
position:absolute;
left:50px;
top:12px;
}

.btngoogle {
-moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #F8A088;
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #F8A088;
box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #f8a088;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#eb5d37', endColorstr='#dc5835',GradientType=0);
background-color:#eb5d37;
-moz-border-radius:3px;
-webkit-border-radius:3px;
border-radius:3px;
border:1px solid #bb4a2b;
display:block;
cursor:pointer;
color:#ffffff;
font-family:Verdana;
font-size:14px;
font-weight:bold;
padding:10px 0;
width:300px;
text-decoration:none;
text-shadow:0px 0.1px 0px #FFFFFF;
margin-top:10px;
position:relative;
}

.fa-google { 
position:absolute;
left:50px;
top:12px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="omb_login">
    <div class="omb_socialButtons">
        <button class="btnfb">
            <i class=" fa fa-facebook" data-size="icon" data-scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();"></i>
                Login With Facebook
        </button>
        <button class="btngoogle">
            <i class="fa fa-google" data-size="icon"></i>
                <a href="<?php echo $google; ?>">
                    Login With Google
                </a>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

of course you can do this but first you should add `display: inline-block` and the `width` you want to the target button then add your `padding`.

Answer (score -1):

`<style>
button
{display:block;
min-width: 300px;}
</style>`

```
<div>
<button> Login with facebook</button>
<button> Login with google+</button>
<button> ?</button>
</div>
```

[image]

This is how you would add min-width to any button component in your application and as you can see even for the button with a question mark the width is equal with all the others.

This ofcoz would change if the text would become more than the min width which is 300px for all the buttons, the button containing a lot more text would expand with the text.

on your `.btngoogle` and `.btnfb`  classes add min-width and give it a value

```
.btngoogle {min-width:300px;}

.btnfb { min-width:300px; }
```